# how to create splines streamlines

Tags: animation-nodes

I am a beginner in Blender and in Animation nodes. Is it possible to somehow achieve simulation of streamlines just like on CFD simulations, but only with splines in Animation nodes?

[image]

That is, splines procedurally flow around any shape. I tried using particles, but I didn’t get anything good. Maybe there’s at least some hint about how this can be implemented.